How to change the font size of page numbers in the TOC of a memoir document
I changed the appearance of the table of contents in a memoir class document using the code shown in my MWE. I would like the titles and page numbers corresponding to subsections and sections typeset in a smaller font size (say, \footnotesize). To do this, I am using the following commands:
    \renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\footnotesize}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\footnotesize}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\footnotesize}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionpagefont}{\footnotesize}

However, as the image shows, while the titles are set in a smaller size, the page numbers remain in \normalsize. Could somebody please help me figure this out?

My MWE is
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

%% New TOC format
% remove leaders (dots between the title of the section and the page number)
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsectionleader}{}

% remove any previous formatting applied to page numbers to ensure that
% page numbers for chapters are displayed in the default font style
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{}

% change font sizes in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionpagefont}{\footnotesize}

% formats the page number for chapter in bold with a bullet point before the number
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{\bfseries~\textbullet~#1}
% formats the page number for sections with a bullet point before the number
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textbullet~#1}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textbullet~#1}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textbullet~#1}

% add a fill space after the page number to ensure proper alignment
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

% right margin of the table of contents is set to a minimum of 3.55em + a flexible space
\setrmarg{3.55em plus 1fil}

% -- Section numbering 
% section numbering includes up to subsubsections
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
% maximum depth of numbering (in the document) is subsubsection
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
% TOC will show up to subsubsections
\settocdepth{subsubsection}

% -- Sets section indentation in TOC
% indentation for sections in the TOC = 2em
\setlength\cftsectionindent{2em}
% indentation for subsections = 4em
\setlength\cftsubsectionindent{4em}
% indentation for subsubsections = 6em
\setlength\cftsubsubsectionindent{6em}

% -- Sets the width of section numbers in the TOC
% chapters
\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{1em}
% sections
\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{2em}
% subsections
\setlength\cftsubsectionnumwidth{2.5em}
% subsubsections
\setlength\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth{3em}

% -------

\title{A Memoir Document}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
This is the first chapter. 

\section{First section 3}
This is the first section of the first chapter. 

\subsection{First subsection 3}
This is the first subsection of first section of the first chapter. 

\subsection{Second subsection 3}
This is the second subsection of first section of the first chapter. 

\subsubsection{First subsubsection 3}
This is the first subsubsection of the second subsection of first section of the first chapter. 

\subsubsection{First subsubsection 3}
This is the second subsubsection of the second subsection of first section of the first chapter. 

\chapter{Second chapter}
This is the second chapter. Continue writing your content here.
    
\end{document}


Not at pc, but I think you removed the page number formatting with your redef og the pnum macros.

As expected you have altered the formatpnum macro so that it no longer used the font command.
In sort of pseudocode, the formatpnum macros are defined as
\newcommand\cftXformatpnum[#1]{%
  \cftXformatpnumhook{#1}%
  \hbox to \@pnumwidth{\hfil\cftXpagefont#1}}

So with your redef you've removed \cftXpagefont. You'll have to reinsert it again.
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{\bfseries~\textbullet~{\cftchapterpagefont #1}}
% formats the page number for sections with a bullet point before the number
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textbullet~{\cftsectionpagefont #1}}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textbullet~{\cftsubsectionpagefont #1}}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textbullet~{\cftsubsubsectionpagefont #1}}

